# Why some dates give worse performance than other in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a query in MS SQL Server asking for name and some date-related information, depending on two dates, a start- and an enddate.

The problem is, I´m not always getting the same performance. Whenever I request something between the dates;

```
2010-07-01 00:00:00.000 and
2011-07-21 23:59:59.999
```

the performance is excellent. I get my result within mseconds. When I request something between these dates, for example,

```
2011-07-01 00:00:00.000 and
2011-07-21 23:59:59.999
```

the performance is.. less than good, taking between 20-28 seconds for each query. Do note how the dates giving good performance is ***more than a year between,*** while the latter is ***20 days.***

Is there any particular reason (maybe related to how DATETIME work) for this?

EDIT: The query,

```
SELECT ENAME, 
    SUM(CASE DATE WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS U2, 
    SUM(CASE DATE WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B_2_4, 
    SUM(CASE DATE WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B_4_8, 
    SUM(CASE DATE WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B_8_16, 
    SUM(CASE DATE WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B_16_24, 
    SUM(CASE DATE WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B_24_48, 
    SUM(CASE DATE WHEN 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS O_48, 
    SUM(CASE DATE WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status, 
    AVG(AVG) AS AVG, 
    SUM(DATE) AS TOTAL

FROM 
    (SELECT ENAME, 
            (CASE 
                WHEN status = 'Ã–ppet' THEN 7 
                WHEN DATE < 48 THEN 
                    (CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN 0 AND 2 THEN 0 
                    WHEN DATE BETWEEN 2 AND 4 THEN 1 
                    WHEN DATE BETWEEN 4 AND 8 THEN 2 
                    WHEN DATE BETWEEN 8 AND 16 THEN 3 
                    WHEN DATE BETWEEN 16 AND 24 THEN 4 
                    WHEN DATE BETWEEN 24 AND 48 THEN 5 
                    ELSE - 1 END) 
            ELSE 6 END) AS DATE, 
            DATE AS AVG
    FROM 
        (SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, cases.date, status.date) AS DATE, 
        extern.name AS ENAME, 
        status.status
    FROM 
        cases INNER JOIN
        status ON cases.id = status.caseid 
                AND status.date =
                    (SELECT MAX(date) AS Expr1
                    FROM status AS status_1
                    WHERE (caseid = cases.id)
                    GROUP BY caseid) INNER JOIN
                    extern ON cases.owner = extern.id
                    WHERE (cases.org = 'Expert') 
                        AND (cases.date BETWEEN '2009-01-15 09:48:25.633' 
                        AND '2011-07-21 09:48:25.633'))
    AS derivedtbl_1) 
AS derivedtbl_2
GROUP BY ENAME
ORDER BY ENAME
```

(parts of) The tables:

```
Extern
    -ID (->cases.owner)
    -name
Cases
    -Owner (->Extern.id)
    -id (->status.caseid)
    -date (case created at this date)
Status
    -caseid (->cases.id)
    -Status
    -Date (can be multiple, MAX(status.date) gives us date when 
     status was last changed)
```

Comment: can you show us your query? it may help

Comment: Was hoping I could avoid that, but sure.

Comment: Any way you could try to boil that down to the simplest case that exhibits the same inconsistent behavior?

Comment: Adding your table schema, indexes, and execution plans for the two distinct queries would be a big help.

Comment: As an aside, do you know that `2011-07-21 23:59:59.999` ultimately becomes `2011-07-22 00:00:00.000`? The granularity of `datetime` is 3 ms (or rather 3.3333…, to be more precise), so if a timestamp ends with `.999`, it rounds up to the beginning of the next second, which in your case means also the next day.

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought a statistics issue.

When you are only selecting the most recent dates these may be unrepresented in the statistics yet as the threshold has not yet been reached that would trigger auto updating.

[See this blog post for an example.](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/03/22/statistics-row-estimations-and-the-ascending-date-column/)